# Get Windows event provider information

Tags: .net, powershell, event-log, trace, etw

I would like to retrieve information about event providers using Windows PowerShell? I'm running Windows 8.1 with PowerShell version 4.0, and I noticed that there are some .NET classes in the [`System.Diagnostics.Eventing` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that offer some functionality around Windows eventing.

I can create an `EventProvider` instance by calling its default constructor, however this does not allow me to get any information about the event providers installed on the system.

```
$EventProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProvider -ArgumentList ([System.Guid]'{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}');
```

How can I get more information about Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) providers that are installed on a system, and interact with Windows event logs, using Windows PowerShell?

I am already aware that I can use the command `logman.exe query providers`, as [described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2593157), to retrieve the ETW provider list, and query the Windows event logs, but this is not very PowerShell friendly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is another .NET namespace called `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader`, which contains a lot more .NET classes that allow you to retrieve information about Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) providers and event logs that are registered with a Windows operating system. Most of these types are defined in the `System.Core.dll` .NET Assembly in the .NET [Global Assembly Cache (GAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example, you can perform the following actions (and more):

- Find out the names of ETW providers installed on a computer
- Discover a complete list of ETW log names present on a computer
- Enumerate metadata related to ETW providers
- Export event log data

### ETW Provider Names

One of the core functions with ETW is getting a list of ETW providers are that are installed on a given system. You can easily retrieve this information with the .NET Framework types in the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace. There just so happens to be a .NET class named `EventLogSession`, and on this class is a static property named `GlobalSession`, which automatically retrieves a session/connection to the Event Log service on the local computer. If necessary, you can alternatively connect to a remote computer by using one of the constructors on the `EventLogSession` class.

Once you have retrieved an instance of the `EventLogSession` class, you can call the `GetProviderNames()` method to retrieve a collection of `String` objects that represent the names of the installed ETW providers on the computer.

Here is an example of retrieving the provider names from the local computer:

```
$EventSession = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession;
$EventProviderNames = $EventSession.GetProviderNames();
$EventProviderNames;
```

Here is an example of retrieving the ETW provider names from a remote computer using an [alternate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351237%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
$EventSession = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession -ArgumentList server01.contoso.com;
$EventProviderNames = $EventSession.GetProviderNames();
$EventProviderNames;
```

You can use a different constructor of the `EventLogSession` class to specify alternate credentials to the remote computer. The [alternate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352836%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `EventLogSession` class requires the following parameters:

- Computer name
- Domain name
- User name
- Password (as a `SecureString`)
- `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.SessionAuthentication` type

Here is an example of how to achieve that:

```
$ComputerName = 'server01.contoso.com';
$Credential   = Get-Credential;
$ArgumentList = $ComputerName, $Credential.UserName.Split('\')[0], $Credential.UserName.Split('\')[1], $Credential.Password, [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.SessionAuthentication]::Default;
$EventSession = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession -ArgumentList $ArgumentList;
```

### ETW Log Names

Once you have discovered all of the ETW providers installed on a computer, you may also wish to explore a complete list of the ETW logs that available on a computer. The `EventLogSession` class also has a method called `GetLogNames()`, which returns a collection of `String` objects that represent the ETW logs available on a target system. Similar to the `GetProviderNames()` method, you can call `GetLogNames()` on a local or remote computer.

Here is an example of retrieving the ETW log names from the local computer:

```
$EventSession = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession;
$EventLogNames = $EventSession.GetLogNames();
$EventLogNames;
```

Here is an example of retrieving the ETW log names from a remote computer:

```
$EventSession = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession -ArgumentList server01.contoso.com;
$EventLogNames = $EventSession.GetLogNames();
$EventLogNames;
```

### ETW Provider Metadata

In addition to retrieving ETW provider names, you might also wish to retrieve more detailed information about them. You can do this using the `ProviderMetadata` class in the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` .NET class. Information provided by the `ProviderMetadata` class includes:

- Provider display name
- Help link (URL)
- Keywords for the provider
- ETW provider ID (GUID)
- Message file path
- Resource file path
- Parameter file path
- Tasks exposed by the provider
- Event metadata for each event declared by the provider

Similar to the ETW provider and ETW log names, you can retrieve provider metadata from the local or remote system. In the latter case, you must establish an `EventLogSession` instance before you attempt to instantiate the `ProviderMetadata` class.

Here is an example of retrieving ETW provider metadata from the local system:

```
# Get the EventLogSession object
$EventSession = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession;
# Get the ETW provider names
$EventProviderNames = $EventSession.GetProviderNames();

# Create an empty array to hold the ProviderMetadata instances
$ProviderMetadataList = @();
# For each ETW provider name ...
foreach ($EventProvider in $EventProviderNames) {
    # Add each ProviderMetadata instance to the array
    $ProviderMetadataList += New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.ProviderMetadata -ArgumentList $EventProvider;
}

# Explore the 16th item from the ProviderMetadata array
$ProviderMetadataList[15];
```

To retrieve ETW provider metadata from a remote system, build your `EventLogSession` object before instantiating the `ProviderMetadata` class, and when you do instantiate `ProviderMetadata`, make sure you pass in the following parameters to the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- ETW provider name
- `EventLogSession` instance
- A `CultureInfo` object

...

```
$ComputerName = 'server01.contoso.com';
$Credential   = Get-Credential;
$SessionArgumentList = $ComputerName, $Credential.UserName.Split('\')[0], $Credential.UserName.Split('\')[1], $Credential.Password, [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.SessionAuthentication]::Kerberos;
$EventSession = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession -ArgumentList $SessionArgumentList;
$EventProviderNames = $EventSession.GetProviderNames();

# Create an empty array to hold the ProviderMetadata instances
$ProviderMetadataList = @();
foreach ($EventProvider in $EventProviderNames) {
    # Build the Arguments for the ProviderMetadata constructor
    $ProviderMetadataArgumentList = $EventProvider, $EventSession, [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture;
    # Add each ProviderMetadata instance to the array
    $ProviderMetadataList += New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.ProviderMetadata -ArgumentList $ProviderMetadataArgumentList;
}

# Explore the 111th item from the array
$ProviderMetadataList[110];
```

**Note**: You might get some exceptions when you instantiate `ProviderMetadata` objects through authenticated connections:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "Attempted to 
>   perform an unauthorized operation."

### Reading ETW Event Logs

Since you mentioned that you wanted to read events from ETW event logs also, this is easy to do with the types in the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` .NET namespace as well. The `EventLogReader` class contains a method called `ReadEvent()` which continually reads the next events from the event log specified when the `EventLogReader` was instantiated.

Here is a simple example of reading events from the System event log:

```
# Instantiate the EventLogReader .NET class
$EventLogReader = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader -ArgumentList 'System';
# Read the first 5 events from the event log
1..5 | % { $EventLogReader.ReadEvent(); };
```

### ETW Event Log Configuration

Similar to the provider metadata retrieved earlier, you can retrieve information about the configuration of a particular ETW event log. To do this, you instantiate the [`EventLogConfiguration` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogconfiguration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), passing in the name of an ETW event log. A variety of information about the event log will be returned, including:

- Log name
- Maximum size (in bytes)
- Provider name(s)
- Log type
- Security descriptor
- Buffer size
- Is log enabled?

Here is an example of how to retrieve this information:

```
$EventSession = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession;
$EventLogNames = $EventSession.GetLogNames();

$EventLogConfigurationList = @();
foreach ($EventLogName in $EventLogNames) {
    $EventLogConfigurationList += New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogConfiguration -ArgumentList $EventLogName;
}
$EventLogConfigurationList[5];
```

Comment: I guess it is for post vista. tried in xp, getting not supported exception.

Comment: Was looking for the message DLL for a specific provider, and you nailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# working in version 5
$providers = Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * | select name
$providers
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to find the source name from the provider name - for example Get-WinEvent displays this complex name "Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" and Event Log displays a friendly name such as "User Profiles Service" then I realised.

Event Log is just removing the "Microsoft-Windows-" which is why the source display name has dashed like "Security-SPP" it's because the provider name "Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" has a dash after chopping off "Microsoft-Windows-".

Same for non-English versions of the operating system.

Yik.